# mocoServer - explanation of code

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have the below lines in one of the projects that I am working on in one of the test classes. I went over mocoServer documentation but wasn't able to understand the below lines. Please can you explain the code listed below?

```
mocoServer.
  request(by(uri("/as/token.oauth2"))).response(contentFromFile(DIR, "token.json"));

mocoServer.request(and(contain(text("Account")))).response(
        with(contentFromFile(TEST_COMMON_DIR, ACCOUNT_RESPONSE)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a *clever* way of naming methods for building objects. It tries to make the code more readable and compact.

I have no idea what this `mocoServer` of yours is or does, but the lines do these things:

**Line 1**: When the mocoServer gets a request on uri "/as/token.oauth2" it will return a response with the contents of the file "token.json" from the directory DIR.

**Line 2**: When the mocoServer gets a request which contains the string "Account", it will return the contents of the file ACCOUNT_RESPONSE from the directory TEST_COMMON_DIR.